# Strange result on the nilradical $N(R)$ of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, nilpotence

I am studying about the nilradical $N(R)$ of a unital ring $R$. In my notes, the **nilradical** of a $R$ is defined as the sum of all nilpotent ideals of $R$.

It says, that $N(R)$ is always a nil ideal, but *not* a nilpotent.

But there is a lemma that it says that the sum of nilpotent ideals is also a nilpotent ideal. Thus, according to this, $N(R)$ should always be nilpotent ideal.

What do I miss?

Comment: in commutative algebra that is not how the traditional definition of the nilradical should look like, however. It is of course a correct characterization.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you for your comment. Indeed, but I m doing a noncommutative algebra course, so I have to cope with this "tough" defiinition.

Comment: in that case the terminology also leaves something to be desired, as a not-necessarily commutative has several (in general) distinct nilradicals...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of *two* (or finitely many) nilpotent ideals is nilpotent. However, infinite sums of nilpotent ideals are not necessarily nilpotent.

Consider, however, the ring
$$
\Bbb R[x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots]/(x_1,x_2^2,x_3^3,\ldots)
$$
Here the nilradical $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ is indeed nil but not nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the problem is on the finiteness on the "summands" of $N(R)$. And thus, if $N(R)$ is a sum of finite nilpotent elements, then it is nilpotent.  Right?

Comment: @Chris Indeed, the sum $\sum_i (x_i)$ in this example is infinite and therefore not (a priori) nilpotent itself even though all the summands are nilpotent.

Comment: Oh, excellent. I had really stuck in this point. Many thanks!